# Networking between two Virtual machines on different hosts

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have openSuse installed as a virtual machine(Oracle Virtual Box) on DeskTop(win 7),  and another openSuse installed on as a virtual machine(Oracle Virtual Box) on my Laptop(win 8.1).

Please see the attached image, in which I have captured the various network adapter information.

I want to network these two VMs, how to achieve this.

The following is the additional information.
Desktop Host machine(win 7)

```
C:\Users\Adofo>ipconfig
Windows IP Configuration
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.invalid
 Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::bd2b:ef06:53ea:740b%11
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.108
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
 Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::35d5:acd3:5f50:fc20%18
 Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.252.32
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:
 Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{DB8941A3-825F-4824-B421-6E1625173A6E}:
 Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.domain.invalid:
  Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
  Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

OpenSuse 12.3 on Virtual Machine: (VirtualBox installed on Desktop, Windows 7)

```
linux-gn77:~ # ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:08:FF:6C  
      inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe08:ff6c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:43 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1180 (1.1 Kb)  TX bytes:9748 (9.5 Kb)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:52 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:52 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:4891 (4.7 Kb)  TX bytes:4891 (4.7 Kb)
```

Laptop: Windows8.1 Host
    C:\Users\Harbir PC>ipconfig
    Windows IP Configuration

```
Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:
 Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:
 Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.invalid
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::555b:6b6a:18c5:9326%3
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.106
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a0d1:2b1d:ba1c:9158%26
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
Tunnel adapter isatap.{AB29F882-C104-4E87-BB48-3C1DDD3136B9}:
 Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Tunnel adapter isatap.domain.invalid:
 Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

OpenSuse 12.3 on Virtual Machine: (VirtualBox installed on Laptop, Windows 8.1)

```
linux-gn77:~/line/client1 # ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:41:7A:77 
      inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe41:7a77/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:57266 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:31879 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:77472539 (73.8 Mb)  TX bytes:2640470 (2.5 Mb)
   lo        Link encap:Local Loopback 
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:5861 (5.7 Kb)  TX bytes:5861 (5.7 Kb)
```

[image]

Comment: How about using `bridged networking` in VMWare and Virtual Box? You can assign IP on both VM at space `192.168.0.0/24`

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to look for "bridged" mod under network configuration in VirtualBox, without that VirtualBox will emulate a small network that nothing can directly communicate with.

Once in bridged mode they should be seen as extra computers to the Router/DHCP server pick up an IP address and you'll be able to communicate with everything on the network segment the host is on.